# $(document).on("input",".SomeClass") works on Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a span with contenteditable tag and I have a function used to detect input into it..

```
//TextArea
<span class="SomeClass" contenteditable></span>

//Function
$(document).on("input", ".SomeClass", function () {
    console.log("input entered");
});
```

This works for me on Chrome but not on the IE 11 or below.
I can't seem to find any mention of it online and was wondering if anyone could give me information on how to get this working or a better approach.

Thanks

Comment: would you post some markup for it, my suggestion is to delegate to the static parent of this element not document.

Comment: I would go to the static parent, but for some reason that does not work with dynamically generated html. this seems to be the only way I can connect with the elements.

Comment: JamesDonnely has answered it. Its a reported bug, so you can't do anything about it but you can do a workaround to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [a reported bug (#794285)](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/794285/ie10-11-input-event-does-not-fire-on-div-with-contenteditable-set) in IE10 and IE11: `contenteditable` elements do not fire the `input` event.

A workaround be to handle different event types alongside `input`, such as `keypress`, `paste` and `change`:

```
$(document).on("input keypress paste change", ".SomeClass", function () {
    console.log("input entered");
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/825ua/3/).

Comment: Hmmm that's unfortunate, Well this is a sufficient solution anyway, thanks. Isn't IE just GREAT!

Comment: @RichardMc are being sarcastic about IE or really praising it? :)

Comment: @jabahar maybe just a little tiny bit of sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a more widely supported event like `keydown` or `keypress` instead of input?

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".SomeClass", function () {
    console.log("input entered");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little complicated, it might use some refactoring, but here you go :

```
var initialState;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    initialState = document.getElementById("span").innerHTML;
});

$(document).keydown( function () {
    var currentState =  document.getElementById("span").innerHTML;
   if( initialState != currentState) {

 console.log("Content changed!");
 }
 });
```

Basically, you "catch" the span when the document is loaded and you add an event listener each time the user presses a key.

Good luck!