# How to tell if a keypress event would generate input

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Some `keypress` events generate input (e.g. normal characters) and some don't (e.g. arrow keys). Is there any way to tell whether a particular `keypress` event is input-generating?

Additional context as requested:

I'm using `contentEditable` to edit text. I would like to pass non-input-generating events (cursor movement, selection, etc.) to the underlying element, but handle input-generating events myself.

Comment: You could try using the "input" event instead, it sounds like what you want. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Comment: Sadly, that won't work in my case - I'm using contentEditable and want to handle input-generating keypresses myself, but pass non-input-generating keypress events to the underlying element.

Comment: arrow keys generate input on selects?

Comment: Ah. Good point - I didn't think of that case. In my case I'm thinking about contentEditable text.

Comment: this sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Perhaps if you add some context to what your trying to achieve?

Comment: @PaulButcher Why wouldn't it work? Binding to `input` means all non-input-generating keypress events would simply perform default action.

Comment: The link @xec provided, says that input event works on contenteditable also. *".. Additionally, it's also fired on contenteditable editors when its contents are changed .."*

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware that input works on contenteditable. But I want to handle the input myself (I don't want default browser behaviour). But I do want default browser behaviour on non-input-generating keypresses.

Comment: The `input` event [doesn't actually work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23930764/1317805) on `contenteditable` elements in IE10 or IE11 thanks to a bug, so binding to `input` alone here unfortunately wouldn't be a good enough solution if you wish to support those two browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that most browsers don't generate keypress events for arrow keys (although this doesn't seem to be guaranteed to be the case by the standard as far as I can see).

In addition, the standard defines a beforeinput event, which looks to be exactly what I want. Except it doesn't actually seem to be implemented by any browsers.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean... maybe you are talking of

**var key = ev? ev.which: window.event.keyCode**

what gives you the key that was pressed, so you can find out if "char" or not...

regards Joachim